# How do I change the keyboard shortcuts for switching TTYs?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, shortcut-keys

After upgrading from Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 to 18.04 I am noticing some conflicting keyboard shortcuts.

I generally using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to bring up the window switcher and then use the arrow keys to navigate while holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Since the upgrade, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> now cycle through TTYs which makes navigating the window switcher only possible by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move right or holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move left.

I have another computer with Arch Linux running GNOME that does not experience this issue so I know it's not a GNOME-only problem.

How do I change the keyboard shortcuts for switching TTYs?

Comment: I found this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=182806
It looks like switching to using Wayland fixes my issue.

Comment: This may help when using Xorg instead of Wayland. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Using_setxkbmap

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1508146
Running

```
$ sudo kbd_mode -s
```

(as suggested in that bug thread) fixed it for me.